# Understanding AS3 parent/child relationships

Tags: actionscript-3, parent-child, flash-cs6

I've looked around the site, but as a beginner, the AS3 lingo is a bit beyond me. I know that parent/child is used to pass information, commands, and variables between scenes and movie clips embedded in each other, but I don't quite understand HOW or WHY it works.

When I say beginner, I mean it. This is my first flash project. In case it helps, this is what I'm trying to do:

I'm making a type effectiveness calculator for Pokemon. I've successfully made 3 movie clip "dials" that will cycle through the different Pokemon Types when buttons on them are pressed. 18 Types, 18 frames per "dial". 19 frames on the third "dial", for a blank type.

I've also made a 4th movie clip that will display the effectiveness, from 0.25x up to 4x.

So, basically, I need to...

1) Pull either a numerical variable (or frame number) up from each of the "dials"

2) Calculate the effectiveness based on those numbers in Scene 1 (or a new, all-inclusive movie clip if that's easier)

3) Then send the result (or desired frame number) down to the 4th movie clip to display the effectiveness.

Aaaaaaaand I have zero clue how to do that. I'd appreciate an explanation as opposed to just telling me how. I WANT to understand.

Thanks in advance, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to understand Object Oriented Programming. Specifically the concept of "containers".  Google "AS3 OOP containers tutorial" and you'll find what you need.